# Can Java program know its current directory?

Tags: java

Is it possible for Java application to know the its own current directory. I am referring to result of `pwd`.

For instance, when executed

```
~/Documents/workspace/Project/bin $ java com/foo/bar/baz/Runner files/text1.txt 
program should know ~/Documents/workspace/Project/bin


~/Documents/workspace/Project $ java com/foo/bar/baz/Runner files/text1.txt 
program should know ~/Documents/workspace/Project
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
File cwd = new File(".");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`System.getProperty("user.dir")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That will return the user's home directory, which is not the same as the directory that the Java program was started from.

Comment: @Jesper No, that's `user.home`. `user.dir` is the current working directory (see list of properties [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29))

Answer (score 4):

This is called the working directory . You can get it with the following instruction :

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: The user's home directory is not the same as the current working directory.

Comment: as @isbadawi said that's user.home. user.dir is the current working directory